# CSESProblemSetGridPaths? why not ac

Tags: c++, algorithm

## CSES Problem Set GridPaths?

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on a C++ program for maze traversal, and I've run into a few issues that I could use some assistance with. The program uses a depth-first search (DFS) algorithm to navigate through a 7x7 grid maze with certain restrictions.

I've encountered unexpected results, and I suspect there might be a bug or oversight in my code. The program is designed to handle different movements ('U', 'R', 'D', 'L') and '?' as a wildcard, allowing the algorithm to explore all possible paths.

I've attached the code below, and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look and provide insights or suggestions on how to improve it. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding why the counts variable doesn't seem to be updating correctly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define B begin()
#define E end()
#define ll long long
#define forin for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
int counts;
int graph[7][7] = {0}; 
map<int,int> m;
pair<int,int> turn[4] = {{0,-1},{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0}};
void dfs(int x,int y,int deep){
    if(x==6&&y==0){
        if(deep==48){
            counts++;
        }
        return;
    }
    graph[x][y] = 1;
    if(m[deep]==-1){
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            int xx = x+turn[i].first;
            int yy = y+turn[i].second;
            if(xx>=0&&xx<7&&yy>=0&&yy<7){
                if(graph[xx][yy]==0){
                    dfs(xx,yy,deep+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        int xx = x+turn[m[deep]].first;
        int yy = y+turn[m[deep]].second;
        if(xx>=0&&xx<7&&yy>=0&&yy<7){
            if(graph[xx][yy]==0){
                dfs(xx,yy,deep+1);
                 
            }
        }
       
    }
    graph[x][y] = 0;
}
int main()
{   
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    counts = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        if(s[i]=='?') m[i] = -1;
        else if(s[i]=='U') m[i] = 0;
        else if(s[i]=='R') m[i] = 1;
        else if(s[i]=='D') m[i] = 2;
        else if(s[i]=='L') m[i] = 3;
    }
    dfs(0,0,0);
    cout << counts;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: link :https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1625

Comment: "I've encountered unexpected results" What unexpected results exactly? Please edit your question to include such additional information

Comment: the results all are 0. and TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED

Comment: The time limit of 1 second makes sure you cannot brute force your way to a solution like you are doing now. The challenge is to find a different way that does not require checking every possible route. The end position of `x==6&&y==0` does not match the way you turn, it should be `x==0&&y==6`.

Comment: but also is TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED